# Oracle Forms - Encountered the synbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following :=.[@%;

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am trying to compile a form in my dev11g environment but I receive 2 errors - Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following :=.[@%;
and 
Encountered the symbol "DEDALL" when expecting one of the following (

**CODE:**

```
test for allowance or deduction in dedall field
if :b1.dedall = 'A' or :b1.dedall = 'B' then
   set_item_property('b1.CLIENT_SPECIFIC_ALLOWANCES', enabled, property_true);
```

**ERROR RETURNED -**

```
Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following :=.[@%;
and 
Encountered the symbol "DEDALL" when expecting one of the following (
```

Anyone any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Comment: What is the first line supposed to be doing? Should it just be a comment?

Comment: Thanks Alex, you are correct. It was just a matter of commenting out this line.

Answer (score 0):

In your example is first line interpreted, Oracle forms does not know such command.
Mark text `test for allowance or deduction in dedall field` as comment like this

```
-- test for allowance or deduction in dedall field
```

Second error can be caused by same reason, compiler didn't find semicolog on preceeding line and continues with next line.

Next reason can be missing

```
end if;
```

in the end of your example (maybe it is in your code?).

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are correct. It was just a matter of commenting out this line. 'test for allowance or deduction in dedall field'